# Visual Studio Python debugger seems to add extra items to lists?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

This happens only when I step through code like this:

```
entries = []
# Here, myObj is a dict
if myObj:
  entries.append(myObj)
```

If I step through above three lines, `entries` has multiple duplicates of myObj, typically 2-4. Immediately following the above code is:

```
for list in [list1, list2, list3]:
  if list: entries.extend(list)
```

When I step through each iteration, `entries` again has duplicates, despite `list1`, for example, having one element and `list2` and `list3` being `None`.

I get *no* duplicates when I run normally, i.e. without any breakpoints. I should mention that this is a multithreaded application (slightly modified [mongo-connector](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector)).

Is there some sort of bug with the VS debugger, or am I doing something wrong in Python?

Comment: Is `entries` shared between threads?

Comment: @user2357112 It's defined like that within the function. It shouldn't be shared then, right?